# How can I get the place where a function is defined in VIM quickly?

Tags: vim, navigation

I've installed `taglist` and `nerdtree` plugins, and I wonder if there's way to quickly find the location where some function is defined, just as what `Control` and pressing function name in `Eclipse` does? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vim` comes with ctags support built in. If you have a `tags` file make sure it can be found by vim by adding it to the tags variable (check if the default works first though)

```
:set tags+=/path/to/tags
```

Then you can use `:tselect SOME_FUNC` to list the file locations. You might only need to type the first characters of the function name and could use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to complete.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I've make a new directory `/usr/include/tags` for `tags` and put `set tags+=/usr/include/tags` into `.vimrc`,and seem still need something?

Comment: @SpawnST does your '/usr/include/tags' directory hold any 'tags' files?

Comment: You need to generate the tags file launching `ctags *.c` from the directory containing your source files. See `man ctags` and also this stackoverflow question for more tips on vim & ctags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks

Comment: @akira,nope,what's `tags files`,how can i generate them?

Comment: okay,finally it's done.

Comment: @SpawnST: read http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the cursor somewhere in the function name and press `Ctrl-]`